# Crosspolicydomain.xml is not working even when placed in root folder where the swf file located

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I have a remote server with IP 192.168.20.41 with tomcat server up and running. 
The IP to access tomcat is 192.168.20.41:9091

I have generated SWF file in my local computer.

The related xml file(data.xml) is placed in remote server in tomcats/webapp/Idea/data.xml folder and is extracted using the following path:

`<mx:HTTPService id="srv" url="http://192.168.20.41:9091/Idea/data.xml"/>`

I am able to see the data of swf file in my local computer but not able to see from any other computer on same network. I have placed the crosspolicydomain.xml in the webapps folder where swf file is located but still I am not able to see any data in swf file. Please help!!

Below is the crosspolicydomain.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- http://www.foo.com/crossdomain.xml --> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="http:support.intense.in:9091/Idea/"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="http:support.intense.in"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="http:support.intense.in:9091/Idea/data.xml"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="192.168.20.41"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="http://192.168.20.41:9091/Idea/data.xml"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="http://192.168.20.41:9091/Idea/"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="http://192.168.20.41:9091/Idea/"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="http://192.168.20.41:9091"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="http://support.intense.in:9091/Idea/data.xml"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="http://support.intense.in:9091/Idea/"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="http://support.intense.in:9091/"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="http://support.intense.in:9091"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Two things to check:  1.  Can you load the crossdomain.xml file manually?  2.  Make sure that you specify `allowInsecureDomain="false"` in your file.

Comment: @Brain: Manually in the sense on the web browser ? or using securityPolicy ?

Comment: I meant in the web browser

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `http://` part from the domain attributes in your crossdomain.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <allow-access-from domain="support.intense.in:9091" to-ports="*" /> 
    <allow-access-from domain="support.intense.in" to-ports="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Also you could use [my Apache module](https://github.com/afarber/mod-socket-policy) to serve the socket policy (and there is [a perl script](https://github.com/afarber/mod-socket-policy/blob/master/socket-policy.pl) available too - for quick and dirty setups. It is still better than many similar scripts - because you can't DOS it by throttling one connection).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what's wrong with crossdomain.xml without being familiar with the whole project, but it might help to try adding this line
    `<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>`

also, sometimes the secure="false" helps, might try this also:
    `<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>`